# Why poll implementation always clear revents?

Tags: linux, io, network-programming, epoll

The [opengroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/poll.html) says

> If the value of fd is less than 0, events is ignored and revents is set to 0 in that entry on return from poll().

and

> **In each pollfd structure, poll() clears the revents member except that where the application requested a report on a condition by setting one of the bits of events listed above**, poll() sets the corresponding bit in revents if the requested condition is true. In addition, poll() sets the POLLHUP, POLLERR and POLLNVAL flag in revents if the condition is true, even if the application did not set the corresponding bit in events.

The [gnulib](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/lib/poll.c)'s implementation always clear revents:

```
  for (i = 0; i < nfd; i++)
  {
      pfd[i].revents = (pfd[i].fd < 0
                    ? 0
                    : compute_revents (pfd[i].fd, pfd[i].events,
                                       &rfds, &wfds, &efds));
      rc += pfd[i].revents != 0;
  }
```

The same as some platform's [glibc](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/unix/bsd/poll.c)

```
for (f = fds; f < &fds[nfds]; ++f)
{
      f->revents = 0;
      ...
```

Comment: Later in the glibc function there is a condition `if (f->fd >= 0)` that might satisfy the requirement.

Comment: No. It has been cleared(set to zero) then.

Comment: Yes but later the code *sets* `revents` *unless* the value is negative. It seems the condition is reversed, but still might work out in the end.

Comment: I see. How to explain "In each pollfd structure, poll() clears the revents member except that where the application requested a report on a condition by setting one of the bits of events listed above". The revents should not be cleared if the event is not set?

Comment: The specification only specifies *behavior* not actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect because it creates a beneficially more consistent `poll` interface.

If I can rely that after `poll` returned `revents` only has set bits for actual events that happened during that poll, then my code can simply loop over them while only looking at and reacting to `revents`.

Of course, negative file descriptors are generally invalid. So there should never be any events on them, and code which acts on them as if they had events, such as the following example, can be reasonably presumed wrong or unintended:

```c
if(pollset[i].revents & POLLIN)
    read(pollset[i].fd, /*...*/);
```

There are many ways by which a pollset file descriptor might be negative.

1. Code which calls `open` or `dup` and assigns the result into the pollset without conditional logic to not do so for the negative error return.
2. Code which temporarily "turns off" a file descriptor from polling by making it negative.
3. Code which tells `poll` to skip a `struct pollfd` entry by setting it to a negative value.

You might think those are wrong or bad design and should not be catered to, but think through how it can reduce boilerplate to handle either of these cases, if you can count on your `poll` implementation doing this "clear `revents`" behavior with negative file descriptors.

Especially because this stuff permeates transitively across API boundaries. If we have to defensively code around the `poll` implementation leaving revents set for negative file descriptors, then

1. some people won't do it, and so
2. if I call `poll` with file descriptors I received from code
   I didn't write or audit, I have to double-check if they're negative,
3. if I use the results of a `poll` from code I didn't write or audit, I have to double-check if the file descriptors are negative,
4. if I pass file descriptors into an API that I didn't write or audit, I have to double-check if they're negative if I suspect that API could call `poll`.

And so on.

More generally, there's a practical elegance in how do-nothing default behaviors tend to compose more usefully with less boilerplate than errors, and always clearing `revents` on negative file descriptors seems like it maximizes that in the code that calls `poll`, including transitively.

The formal specification might not care enough to talk about these design considerations, and these interfaces are from a time when software design best practices were much less mature, but modern implementations have been shaped by lots of cumulative usage and experience, and if they can do better while not violating the interface, they try to.

And what do we lose? The ability to use `revents` as data storage across `poll` calls, but only if the `fd` is negative? Is that more common or more valuable than all of the above?